# Livewire display issue when value changes from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-livewire

I have an issue with display updates when updating quantities.  I have left/right arrows next to a number in a table to allow the user to change the value of the number, like this:
[image: spinner]

When the user clicks the left button, a Livewire action triggers that removes an association from a belongs-to-many relationship.  When the user clicks the right button, a Livewire action triggers that adds an association to the belongs-to-many relationship.

The Livewire action then refreshes the model, so that the dynamic model property which counts the number of associated records is updated for the Livewire component.

When the number reaches 0, the left arrow disappears.  When the number reaches the total quantity available, the right arrow disappears.

Everything about this component works great, except that whenever the values changes **from 0 to 1** or **from 1 to 0**, the numeral disappears from the display:

toggle to 0 [image: toggle to 0]

toggle to 1 [image: toggle to 1]

Everything else in my component works flawlessly, including other functionality that relies on the value that disappears.  Interacting with any other action in my component causes the number to magically reappear.

If I add a `<?php dump($widget->my_associated) ?>` to my blade, the correct value gets dumped each time.  See example from toggling to 1 or to 4:

[image: toggle with dump]

This is the code for my component:

shop-widgets.blade.php

```
<td align="center">
        <span style="white-space:nowrap;">
        @if ($widget->my_associated)
            <a href="#" wire:click="release(false)"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-caret-left"></i></a>
        @else
            <i class="fas fa-fw"></i>
        @endif
        {{ $widget->my_associated }}<?php dump($widget->my_associated) ?>
        @if ($widget->remaining)
            <a href="#" wire:click="reserve(false)"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-caret-right"></i></a>
        @else
            <i class="fas fa-fw"></i>
        @endif
        </span>
    </td>
```

ShopWidgets.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Widget;

class ShopWidgets extends Component
{
    public $widget;

    public function mount(Widget $widget)
    {
        $this->widget = $widget;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.shop-widgets', [
            'widget' => $this->widget,
        ]);
    }

    public function reserve($bought) {
        $this->widget->reserve($bought);
        $this->widget->refresh();
    }

    public function release($bought) {
        $this->widget->release($bought);
        $this->widget->refresh();
    }
}
```

Widget.php

```
    public function reserve($bought)
    {
        Gate::authorize('reserve', $this);
        if ($this->remaining > 0) {
            $this->buyers()->attach(Auth::user()->id, ['bought' => $bought]);
        }
    }

    public function release($bought)
    {
        Gate::authorize('release', $this);
        $pivot = $this->buyers()->newPivotStatementForId(Auth::user()->id)->where('bought', $bought);
        if ($pivot->count() > 0)
        {
            $pivot->limit(1)->delete();
        }
    }
```

Any idea what might be causing the display issue for this very specific circumstance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after playing around with this a bit more, I realized that the dump is probably displaying correctly because it was inside a `<div>`.  So, I put the number display inside a `<span>` and it seems to have fixed my issue...  `<span>{{ $widget->my_associated }}</span>`

If anyone knows why this is occurring, I'd be curious to know for troubleshooting future issues...